# laravel package / service provider view refactor, how to fallback to a view location definition in case the view is not found?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, service-provider, laravel-views

I had to do this:

[Take a created laravel app, a way to create something like 2 apps that share a core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44489023/take-a-created-laravel-app-a-way-to-create-something-like-2-apps-that-share-a-c)

so i created a package of the existing app. Now all views need to be prefixed with something like

`myappcore::`

now I can do that but it will take long and will be error prone. Is there no way to try to access a view, and if not found, try to access the view automatically via `myappcore::` ?

Answer (score 0):

You simply create a directory structure under resources for the views like this:

```
resources/views/vendor/package_name
```

It just needs to mirror what exists in the package.